# How to remove Firefox & temp file for Firefox in Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, firefox, uninstall

How to remove old version Firefox and how remove temp file for Firefox in Ubuntu ?

How to remove old version Firefox and install new Firefox 19.0 in Ubuntu?

Comment: Can you please add more information about your problem? What version of Firefox is it you want to remove? How did you install this version? What version of Firefox do you want to install? How are you trying to install it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Synaptic installed simply type in the search-field Firefox and mark it for **complete removal** (this action will include removal of your hidden files and translation files if installed).

Then open the Softwarecenter and type Firefox click for installation, this action will give you the latest Firefox (19 at this moment) installed.

For eventual translations of FF re-open Synaptic and search for firefox-locale-xx (xx is the language of your choise) . Use this only when translation is required.

Synaptic is a very handy program so if you don't have it first install it via the Softwarecenter.

Succes !

Answer (score 0):

just run these commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install firefox
```

this command will update firefox to version 19 (laatest now)
as for temp files, ubuntu manages them nicely and they'll be cleaned automatically for your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

To remove temporary system files as well as firefox I suggest you install Bleachbit first:

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install bleachbit

after installation open it and select files which you want to remove.